# Автоматическая отправка формы без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, мне нужно отправить форму без перезагрузки страницы, с дальнейшими действиями на странице, то-есть после отправки формы нужно еще кликнуть подтверждающее выплывающее меню, как это можно реализовать посредством JS?

Answer (score 1):

Это можно реализовать при помощи [AJAX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX).

Для работы с AJAX можно использовать какую-нибудь библиотеку (например, jQuery) или написать всё на чистом JS. Первое, ИМХО, более предпочтительно.

Comment: Есть, сайт на котором присутствует чат, а я пишу расширение для браузера что бы при входе на него в чат отправлялось от меня сообщение, но там нету ни кнопки отправить ничего, то-есть отправить сообщение только по нажатию на enter можно, пробовал отправлять через через форму-страница перезагружается, а там после отправки должно выйти окно где нужно подтвердить вход.

Comment: @SloGS, как говорится, каков вопрос таков и ответ. Но, даже при такой постановке задачи без AJAX Вам, скорее всего. не обойтись.

Comment: А ведь сайт не мой, а при отправки сообщения по enter, разве там используется ajax?

Извините за неправильно сформулированный вопрос.

Comment: @SloGS суть то не в ajax (но да, он вам и нужен). А в том что вы не знаете как с ним работать, почитайте документацию. В интернете огромной  количество примеров в этим. Даже тут на сайте, этот вопрос неоднократно поднимался.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно в обработчик

```
   $(document).ready(function () {}); поместить функцию вызова ajax: 

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: {
            Id: Data1,
            Name: Data2,
            Message: Data3
        },                  
        success: function (data) {
            $("#pro").html(data);                       
        }
    }
    )
};
```

Ну соответственно в ajax все что Вам требуется