# PHP форма заказа

Tags: php

Есть скрипт PHP (форма заявки на сайте), когда нажимаю отправить?, страница с главной переходит на http//сайт123/form1.php в пустое окно. 
Вопрос: Как сделать что бы после отправки формы, был возврат на главную в срабатывало popup окно(оно прописано уже в html)"Спасибо за заявку" ?

```
<?php
// несколько получателей
$to  = 'culik.dima2017@yandex.ru' . ', ';  // обратите внимание на запятую
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// тема письма
$subject = 'Письмо с моего сайта';

// текст письма
$message = 'Пользователь' . $_POST['name'] . ' отправил вам письмо:<br />' . $_POST['message'] . '<br />
Связяться с ним можно по phone11 <a href="mailto:' . $_POST['phone11'] . '">' . $_POST['phone11'] . '</a>'
;

// Для отправки HTML-письма должен быть установлен заголовок Content-type
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

// Дополнительные заголовки
$headers .= 'To: Иван <Ivan@example.com>' . "\r\n"; // Свое имя и phone11
$headers .= 'From: '  . $_POST['name'] . '<' . $_POST['phone11'] . '>' . "\r\n";


// Отправляем
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Используйте AJAX для этих целей, отправляйте данные на нужный обработчик, а в случае неудачи/успеха вызывайте попап с нужным сообщением

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Автоматическая отправка формы без перезагрузки страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520752/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)

Answer (score 0):

```
function send_post(url, data){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, true);

xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState != 4) return;

   //Тут отправляем "Спасибо за Вашу заявку!"
}

xhr.send(data);
}

var data = "name=name&message=message&phone11=phone11и.т.д";
var url = "http//сайт123/form1.php";
send_post(url, data);
```

Comment: Не работает Ваш код:

<?php

function send_post(url, data){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, true);

xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState != 4) return;

   //Тут отправляем "Спасибо за Вашу заявку!"
}

xhr.send(data);
}

var data = "name=name&message=message&phone11=phone11и.т.д";
var url = "http//my-puff.ru/form1.php";
send_post(url, data);
?>

Comment: Что консоль выдает?

Comment: переходит на  http://my-puff.ru/form1.php, Страница недоступна

Сайт my-puff.ru пока не может обработать этот запрос.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Ну так тут ошибка в самом php скрипте, а не в коде который я написал. Переменная data как у Вас выглядит?

Comment: я не особо разбираюсь в php, что должно быть на месте data ?

Comment: Да тут не php. Тут POST запрос. Вот тут $message = 'Пользователь' . $_POST['name'] . ' отправил вам письмо:<br />' . $_POST['message'] . '<br /> Вы должны получить name и message из пост запроса например. Соответственно п POST запросе должны быть name=vasia&message=good. Так же есть $_POST['phone11'] соответственно должна быть и phone11 итого переменная data должна выглядеть var data = "name=vasia&message=good&phone=+71234567812". А вообще функция mail может в принципе не работать если на сервер не установлен соответствующий софт. Кроме того ошибка 500 говорит именно об ошибке в php